# MongoDB Atlas Error with Mongodb Terraform Providers

Tags: mongodb-atlas

Getting the below error from running TF apply, Plan works okay since it's only showing what resources would be provisioned and not interacting with the API

```
module.mongodb_endpoint["0"].mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_serverless.this[0]: Creating...

Error: error adding MongoDB Serverless PrivateLink Endpoint Connection(): https://cloud.mongodb.com/api/atlas/v2/groups/xxxx/privateEndpoint/serverless/instance/auto-provisioning-prod/endpoint POST: HTTP 401 Unauthorized (Error code: "") Detail: You are not authorized for this resource. Reason: Unauthorized. Params: [] 

with module.mongodb_endpoint["0"].mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_serverless.this[0],  
on ../../../../modules/auto-provisioning/mongodb_privatelink/endpoint/main.tf line 1, in resource "mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_serverless" "this": 
1: resource "mongodbatlas_privatelink_endpoint_serverless" "this" {
```

I am using data source to get the API keys from AWS secret Manager and passing it to the mongodb atlas

```
provider “mongodbatlas” {
public_key = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.public_key.secret_string
private_key = data.aws_secretsmanager_secret_version.private_key.secret_string
}
```

I have tested the API keys using curl command and I can see that they can interact with the Mongodb API endpoints successfully, but just doesnt work in my Terraform script when trying to deploy